# Why does a simple use of ostringstream generates so much assembly code?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang++, ostream, code-size

Consider the following simple example that formats a string and an integer using `ostringstream` and discards the output:

```
#include <sstream>

void ostringstream_test() {
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << "x = " << 42;
  ss.str();
}
```

Compiling it with `clang++ -S -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++14 test.cc` generates a ton of assembly code (half a kilobyte in x86-64 instructions compared to less than a hundred bytes for a similar `sprintf` code) - see below the output. Why does it generates so much code, is it inherent to the `ostringstream` API or this particular compiler/library does something wrong?

```
    .globl  __Z18ostringstream_testv
    .p2align    4, 0x90
__Z18ostringstream_testv:               ## @_Z18ostringstream_testv
Lfunc_begin0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 155, ___gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 16, Lexception0
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Lcfi0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Lcfi1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Lcfi2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $328, %rsp              ## imm = 0x148
Lcfi3:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -56
Lcfi4:
    .cfi_offset %r12, -48
Lcfi5:
    .cfi_offset %r13, -40
Lcfi6:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -32
Lcfi7:
    .cfi_offset %r15, -24
    leaq    -256(%rbp), %r14
    leaq    -360(%rbp), %r12
    movq    __ZTCNSt3__119basic_ostringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE0_NS_13basic_ostreamIcS2_EE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    leaq    24(%rax), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -368(%rbp)
    addq    $64, %rax
    movq    %rax, -256(%rbp)
Ltmp0:
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    movq    %r12, %rsi
    callq   __ZNSt3__18ios_base4initEPv
Ltmp1:
## BB#1:
    movq    $0, -120(%rbp)
    movl    $-1, -112(%rbp)
    movq    __ZTVNSt3__119basic_ostringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbx
    leaq    24(%rbx), %r13
    movq    %r13, -368(%rbp)
    addq    $64, %rbx
    movq    %rbx, -256(%rbp)
Ltmp3:
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__115basic_streambufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEC2Ev
Ltmp4:
## BB#2:
    movq    __ZTVNSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r15
    addq    $16, %r15
    movq    %r15, -360(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -272(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -280(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -288(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -296(%rbp)
    movl    $16, -264(%rbp)
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, -80(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -64(%rbp)
Ltmp6:
    leaq    -80(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE3strERKNS_12basic_stringIcS2_S4_EE
Ltmp7:
## BB#3:
    testb   $1, -80(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_5
## BB#4:
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZdlPv
LBB0_5:
Ltmp9:
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rsi
    leaq    -368(%rbp), %rdi
    movl    $4, %edx
    callq   __ZNSt3__124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m
Ltmp10:
## BB#6:
Ltmp11:
    movl    $42, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEElsEi
Ltmp12:
## BB#7:
Ltmp13:
    leaq    -104(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    %r12, %rsi
    callq   __ZNKSt3__115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE3strEv
Ltmp14:
## BB#8:
    testb   $1, -104(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_10
## BB#9:
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZdlPv
LBB0_10:
    movq    %r13, -368(%rbp)
    movq    %rbx, -256(%rbp)
    movq    %r15, -360(%rbp)
    testb   $1, -296(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_12
## BB#11:
    movq    -280(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZdlPv
LBB0_12:
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__115basic_streambufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEED2Ev
    movq    __ZTTNSt3__119basic_ostringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    addq    $8, %rsi
    leaq    -368(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEED2Ev
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__19basic_iosIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEED2Ev
    addq    $328, %rsp              ## imm = 0x148
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r12
    popq    %r13
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_13:
Ltmp8:
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    testb   $1, -80(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_18
## BB#14:
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZdlPv
    testb   $1, -296(%rbp)
    jne LBB0_19
    jmp LBB0_20
LBB0_16:
Ltmp5:
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    jmp LBB0_21
LBB0_15:
Ltmp2:
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    jmp LBB0_22
LBB0_17:
Ltmp15:
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    movq    %r13, -368(%rbp)
    movq    %rbx, -256(%rbp)
    movq    %r15, -360(%rbp)
LBB0_18:
    testb   $1, -296(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_20
LBB0_19:
    movq    -280(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZdlPv
LBB0_20:
    movq    %r12, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__115basic_streambufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEED2Ev
LBB0_21:
    movq    __ZTTNSt3__119basic_ostringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    addq    $8, %rsi
    leaq    -368(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEED2Ev
LBB0_22:
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__19basic_iosIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEED2Ev
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdi         ## 8-byte Reload
    callq   __Unwind_Resume
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
    .section    __TEXT,__gcc_except_tab
    .p2align    2
GCC_except_table0:
Lexception0:
    .byte   255                     ## @LPStart Encoding = omit
    .byte   155                     ## @TType Encoding = indirect pcrel sdata4
    .asciz  "\303\200"              ## @TType base offset
    .byte   3                       ## Call site Encoding = udata4
    .byte   65                      ## Call site table length
Lset0 = Ltmp0-Lfunc_begin0              ## >> Call Site 1 <<
    .long   Lset0
Lset1 = Ltmp1-Ltmp0                     ##   Call between Ltmp0 and Ltmp1
    .long   Lset1
Lset2 = Ltmp2-Lfunc_begin0              ##     jumps to Ltmp2
    .long   Lset2
    .byte   0                       ##   On action: cleanup
Lset3 = Ltmp3-Lfunc_begin0              ## >> Call Site 2 <<
    .long   Lset3
Lset4 = Ltmp4-Ltmp3                     ##   Call between Ltmp3 and Ltmp4
    .long   Lset4
Lset5 = Ltmp5-Lfunc_begin0              ##     jumps to Ltmp5
    .long   Lset5
    .byte   0                       ##   On action: cleanup
Lset6 = Ltmp6-Lfunc_begin0              ## >> Call Site 3 <<
    .long   Lset6
Lset7 = Ltmp7-Ltmp6                     ##   Call between Ltmp6 and Ltmp7
    .long   Lset7
Lset8 = Ltmp8-Lfunc_begin0              ##     jumps to Ltmp8
    .long   Lset8
    .byte   0                       ##   On action: cleanup
Lset9 = Ltmp9-Lfunc_begin0              ## >> Call Site 4 <<
    .long   Lset9
Lset10 = Ltmp14-Ltmp9                   ##   Call between Ltmp9 and Ltmp14
    .long   Lset10
Lset11 = Ltmp15-Lfunc_begin0            ##     jumps to Ltmp15
    .long   Lset11
    .byte   0                       ##   On action: cleanup
Lset12 = Ltmp14-Lfunc_begin0            ## >> Call Site 5 <<
    .long   Lset12
Lset13 = Lfunc_end0-Ltmp14              ##   Call between Ltmp14 and Lfunc_end0
    .long   Lset13
    .long   0                       ##     has no landing pad
    .byte   0                       ##   On action: cleanup
    .p2align    2
```

Comment: Clang version? Just to test

Comment: Because iostreams are an flexible, extensible, modern C++ API with all the virtual functions and registerable locale facets that you could ever want. Who knows, maybe one day you'll want to imbue that stringstream with a custom currency separator symbol?

Comment: clang --version: "Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)"

Comment: If you only want to format a number in a string, better use `std::string s = "x = " + std::to_string(42);` or similar.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand the advantages of ostreams, but my question is more about whether it's normal that per-call code size is so large.

Comment: @KerrekSB: a decent implementation of IOstreams still doesn’t need to create so much code. Using explicit instantiations can bring down the created code quite easily without any loss if flexibility. Being careful about what to inline and what not can also improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason for the difference is that the IOStream implementation is expanded inline while the `sprintf()` use is just a function call. Nothing inherently prevents IOStreams to be implemented by a library. It does take a tiny but of abstraction and planning, though: the definition in the standard uses templates. These are normally just implemented inline. Declaring the typically used instantiations (for character types `char` and `wchar_t`) as `extern` templates and explicitly instantiating them is extra work, though. I showed a long time ago that it does pay off in term of compile-time and, at least, libstdc++ preinstantiates the IOStreams functions in a library. Based on you experiment it seems libc++ doesn’t.

Comment: Does libstdc++ externalize those definitions? If so, maybe we can see a big difference on godbolt?

Comment: @KerrekSB: AFAIK libstdc++ does externalize the IOStream definitions. My own implementation prototyped that approach [at a point in time where there were no `extern` template declarations, though, i.e., there was some faffing about with macros conditionally including the definitions or not].